# How to write the log likelihood for a full model of a negative binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, negative-binomial-distribution, likelihood

I would like to know how to write the log likelihood for a full model of a negative binomial distribution to test a null hypothesis that population mean group1 = population mean group2 vs not equal (i.e. H0 : mu1 = mu2 vs H1 mu1 != mu2). The intention is to do a likelihood ratio test.

The Negative binomial distribution in written in terms of mean mu and dispersion parameter k, using the Gamma function.

Sorry I do not know how to enter the equations in. I would like to know how to write the likelihood function for the full model and thereby obtain the log likelihood. Also, how does the full model differ from the reduced model/null model? Hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance